# GET Variable lost on RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache

I have written a redirect to change quiz.php?quiz=1 to /quiz/1 however PHP can no longer pickup the GET Variables, is there anything i'm missing? This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^quiz/([^/]*)$ /quiz.php?quiz=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have error in RewriteRule ^quiz/([^/]*)$ /quiz.php?quiz=/$1 [QSA,L]
   There should not be slash at redirect target, so correct is `RewriteRule ^quiz/([^/]*)$ /quiz.php?quiz=$1 [QSA,L]`
2. I tried this on localhost and it is working properly. Try debugging via e.g. var_dump($_GET);

Comment: Yeah, think my WAMP is playing up, as even if i remove my htaccess the redirect still happens. Does Apache cache htaccess files at all? Its not my browser as i have cleared my cache + tried a differnt browser

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, you probably need to disable content negociation and `AcceptPathInfo` features by adding the following lines to your .htaccess file:

```
AcceptPathInfo off
Options -MultiViews
```

Content negociation can internally "rewrite" "quiz" into "quiz.php". And `AcceptPathInfo` "quiz.php/a/b/c" to "quiz.php" with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` = '/a/bc/c'. They both happen before rewriting, bypassing your rule.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Your answer combined with Daniel's worked :)